# why am i receiving a error when installing argon on a fresh laravel install?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install the Argon template for laravel on a fresh install, apart from filling in the .env with the database information which works i haven't done anything to this install of laravel, the guide im following when installing the theme is the official one in the argon docs at this link: https://argon-dashboard-laravel.creative-tim.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start.html

The instructions are

```
Cd to your Laravel app
Install this preset via composer require laravel-frontend-presets/argon. No need to register the service provider. Laravel 5.5 & up can auto detect the package.
Run php artisan preset argon command to install the Argon preset. This will install all the necessary assets and also the custom auth views, it will also add the auth route in routes/web.php (NOTE: If you run this command several times, be sure to clean up the duplicate Auth entries in routes/web.php)
In your terminal run composer dump-autoload
Run php artisan migrate --seed to create basic users table
```

and when running `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/argon`

i recieve the error

```
λ  composer require laravel-frontend-presets/argon
Using version ^1.0 for laravel-frontend-presets/argon
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.1 requires laravel/framework 5.5 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon v1.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.0.7, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.2
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.0, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.1, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.2, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.3, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.4, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.5, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.6, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.7, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v7.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v7.0.7].
    - laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.0 requires laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel-frontend-presets/argon ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel-frontend-presets/argon[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, v1.0.10].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Aragon requires Laravel 5.5, you are using Laravel 7.

Comment: first line : laravel-frontend-presets/argon 1.0.1 requires laravel/framework 5.5

Comment: You can use laravel 6.x if you use argon 1.0.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are required to update you Laravel version

you could use this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade to try upgrading it or a fresh install of your laravel framework